# How can I apply Rouche's Theorem here?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, polynomials, exponential-function, roots

How many solutions lie in the left half-plane?

$$f(z) = z^3+2z^2-z-2+e^z=0$$

My work so far:

Factoring the polynomial, moving the exponential term over to the RHS, and taking the modulus of both sides gives me:

$$|(z+1)(z+2)(z-1)| = |e^{-x}| = \frac{1}{e^x} < 1$$

The obvious numbers that fulfill the above inequality are the roots -1,-2,+1, which makes the LHS = 0.

Among these numbers, -1 and -2 are from the left half-plane, so I have two solutions.

...do I have more solutions?  How could I apply Rouche's Theorem here?

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Factor the polynomial part $p(z)$ and note that $|p(z)|\geq 2$ on the imaginary axis as well as on the circle $|z|=3$.

Comment: I finally got it @WimC, after working out the lower bound for the polynomial.  Thanks so much :-)